# JasperReports Server: Hide columns in report depend on username login

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I use *iReport 5.0.0* and *JasperReports Server 5.0.0* too. I have some problem that if I login in *JR Server* with UserName as Admin I would like *JS* to show the column (that I need) but when I login as userName Test1, *JS* doesn't show the column. And the right to access this column I use table to store it such as I have 2 fields, UserName and AccessRight.

Please advise me to do this because I'm new in *JR Server + iReport* and I have searched in Google I'm not find this topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In I-report you need to Use the "print When Expression"

example using Groovy as your report language

```
$P{LoggedInUsername} == "Admin" ? true :false
```

or with JAVA

```
($P{LoggedInUsername}.toString().contains("Admin"))?new Boolean(true) : new Boolean(false)
```

you may want to do this by user roles as the if the statement can get ugly if you have more than 1 user you want to to see the column.

[JasperSoft  Community Docs][1]http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/built-parameters-logged-user

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But I want to use table to store value to access this column such as username = "admin" access_right = "y" or username = "test1" access_right = 'n' and so on. Please advise me to do this.

Comment: I am not sure i understand.  you can do this sort of access control with a Domain in jasper server.  Other wise you could do this as part of the SQL statement maybe with a case statement.  [Domain Docs](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/defining-domain-security-file)

Comment: Thank you very much for your kindness. I do it in case statement and it's work. Thank you again for your help.